# How to avoid creating an extra li element

Tags: javascript

I'm expanding my "forms" skills and I have created that code.

```js
const select = document.querySelector('select');
const input = document.querySelector('input');

select.addEventListener('change', chceckIndex)
input.addEventListener('change', addPhoto)

let selectedValue;

function chceckIndex(e) {
  selectedValue = e.target.value
}

function addPhoto(e) {
  if (selectedValue == null || selectedValue == '') {
    alert('Please select your section');
    return
  }
  for (const element of e.target.files) {
    if (element.type.includes('image')) {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function(readerEvent) {
        const selectedUl = document.querySelector(`.images-list__${selectedValue}`)
        const newLi = selectedUl.querySelector('li');
        const clonedLi = newLi.cloneNode(true);
        selectedUl.appendChild(clonedLi);
        const newHeader = clonedLi.querySelector('header');
        newHeader.innerText = element.name;
        const newImg = clonedLi.querySelector('img');
        newImg.src = readerEvent.target.result;
        const newFooter = clonedLi.querySelector('footer');
        newFooter.innerText = `${(element.size / 1048576).toFixed(2)} MB`;
        clonedLi.classList.remove('visibility');
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(element);
    } else {
      alert('Please choose proper format of your file')
    }
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.images-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

li {
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  max-width: 20%;
}

.visibility {
  display: none;
}

header {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

footer {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<label for="section-select">Choose a section:</label>
<select name="sections" id="section-select">
  <option value="">--Please choose where you want to store your photos--</option>
  <option value="vacation">Vacation</option>
  <option value="birthday">Birthday</option>
  <option value="others">Others</option>
</select>
<input type="file" multiple>
<ul class="images-list images-list__vacation">
  <h1>Vacation</h1>
  <li class="visibility">
    <header></header>
    <img src="" alt="">
    <footer></footer>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul class="images-list images-list__birthday">
  <h1>Birthdayy</h1>
  <li class="visibility">
    <header></header>
    <img src="" alt="">
    <footer></footer>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul class="images-list images-list__others">
  <h1>Others</h1>
  <li class="visibility">
    <header></header>
    <img src="" alt="">
    <footer></footer>
  </li>
</ul>
```

...and I would like to...

1. Avoid creating an extra 'li' element but I still want to use `cloneNode` method
2. If I did not choose any section I would like to not upload any file by default and do not show its name. I mean this:

[image]

Do you have any advice how I can improve my code? I would be grateful.

Comment: I don't understand, what extra li?

Comment: You can use `e.preventDefault()` for #2.

Comment: Barmar if u click F12 u will see an extra li element in DOM, for example if i add 3 images there would be 4 li elements and i was trying to use `e.preventDefault()` but that did not work,are u sure?

Comment: The first one is the empty one that you cloned. You need to keep that around so yuo can clone it again for other images.

Comment: Why don't you put the element that you're cloning in a `<template>`?

Comment: Ok but is it wrong when i have an empty li elemnt in DOM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Put the `li` that you're cloning in a separate invisible `ul`, not inside the `ul` that you're appending to.
2. Set the value of the input to `null` to clear the file.

```js
const select = document.querySelector('select');
const input = document.querySelector('input');

select.addEventListener('change', chceckIndex)
input.addEventListener('change', addPhoto)

let selectedValue;

function chceckIndex(e) {
  selectedValue = e.target.value
}

function addPhoto(e) {
  if (selectedValue == null || selectedValue == '') {
    alert('Please select your section');
    e.target.value = null;
    return
  }
  for (const element of e.target.files) {
    if (element.type.includes('image')) {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function(readerEvent) {
        const selectedUl = document.querySelector(`.images-list__${selectedValue}`)
        const newLi = document.querySelector('#li-template li');
        const clonedLi = newLi.cloneNode(true);
        selectedUl.appendChild(clonedLi);
        const newHeader = clonedLi.querySelector('header');
        newHeader.innerText = element.name;
        const newImg = clonedLi.querySelector('img');
        newImg.src = readerEvent.target.result;
        const newFooter = clonedLi.querySelector('footer');
        newFooter.innerText = `${(element.size / 1048576).toFixed(2)} MB`;
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(element);
    } else {
      alert('Please choose proper format of your file')
    }
  }
  e.target.value = null;
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.images-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

li {
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  max-width: 20%;
}

.visibility {
  display: none;
}

header {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

footer {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<label for="section-select">Choose a section:</label>
<select name="sections" id="section-select">
  <option value="">--Please choose where you want to store your photos--</option>
  <option value="vacation">Vacation</option>
  <option value="birthday">Birthday</option>
  <option value="others">Others</option>
</select>
<input type="file" multiple>
<ul class="images-list images-list__vacation">
  <h1>Vacation</h1>
</ul>
<ul class="images-list images-list__birthday">
  <h1>Birthdayy</h1>
</ul>
<ul class="images-list images-list__others">
  <h1>Others</h1>
</ul>

<ul id="li-template" class="visibility">
  <li>
    <header></header>
    <img src="" alt="">
    <footer></footer>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks mate its my first time with <template>

Comment: Btw any advice what could i do better?

Comment: Hmm i might be wrong but your code dose not work, something wrong with cloneNode, but i dont know why it seems fairly good

Comment: The template didn't work for me, either, I changed it to an invisible DIV.

Comment: Thanks it works perfectly now, btw why `e.preventDefault()` did not work here?